# Ler vários números de scanf separados por espaço e colocar num vector em C

Tags: c

Estou precisando fazer um programa que recebe uma quantidade de elementos e colocar um vetor, mais eu quero colocar os elementos no **scanf** separados por espaço e depois passar no vector. Só que eu não sei como fazer isso, alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow, recomendamos que ao menos você tente implementar algo referente à sua necessidade, caso ainda exista dúvidas, adicione o código para que possamos lhe ajudar!

Comment: você quer que ele calcule automaticamente a quantidade de numeros inseridos? ou que pegue a partir de um for?

Comment: Você quer que na entrada os elementos estejam separados por espaço? Isto dependerá do tipo de dado sendo lido, exceto para a especificação de conversão contendo:[, c, C, ou n, o scanf considerará um ou mais carateres de espaço em branco ( <espaço>, <tab>, <novalinha>, <vertical-tab>, ou <form-feed>) como um separador entre os elementos sendo lidos. Para ler os elementos de um array de elementos normalmente se utiliza um loop for e a variável de controle do loop como índice do array.

Comment: Não deu para perceber o que você quer fazer em concreto ? Comece por explicar o mais detalhadamente possível. Inclua também o código que já tem desenvolvido pois ajuda a perceber as suas questões.

Answer (score 2):

A pergunta não está muito clara pra mim, porém não tenho pontuação para comentar, então vou responder baseado em que eu entendi.

De acordo com o que eu interpretei você quer ler vários números num único `scanf` e salvar em um vetor.

Código:

```
int vetor[4];
scanf( "%i %i %i %i", &vetor[0], &vetor[1], &veto[2], &vetor[3]);
```

Se não for isso que deseja eu apago a resposta sem problemas!

Comment: Por que não: for (i=0; i<4; i++) scanf("%i", &vetor[i]); ?

Comment: Porque pelo modo que foi perguntado, me parece que ele não quer usar uma estrutura de repetição. Veja na pergunta: "mais eu quero colocar os elementos no `scanf` separados por espaço e depois passar no vector", quando ele diz: "separados por espaço", deu de entender(pelo menos pra mim) que ele queria ler vários valores em apenas um `scanf` e salvar os mesmos num vetor.

Comment: Concordo integralmente com você a respeito de que a pergunta está muito mal formulada.